# Disable yum transaction check for file conflict

Tags: linux, yum

How do I disable yum transaction check for a file ?

```
Transaction check error:
  file /usr/local/xenco/backend/current from install of xenco-rr-1.9.6-104.x86_64 conflicts with file from package xenco-server-1.9.6-104.x86_64
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Replacing files from another RPM package is bad idea in most cases and I strongly advise against what you're trying to do. That said, apply following at your own risk.

Yum does not provide an option to install conflicting files, I think. However, that does not prevent you from installing a RPM package with rpm(1) which *does* provide an option to override existing files from another package, namely `--replacefiles`.

So, first get the RPM of the package you want to install on a local filesystem (`/usr/local/xenco...` makes me suspect that is the case already). Next install the RPM with `rpm -i --replacefiles <your_rpm_file>`.

Comment: +1 for actually providing answer on how to do that. while this may be a "bad idea" in some cases, there are also cases where it's not a bad idea at all, just a bad packaging by vendor and overwriting does nothing bad.

Comment: note that `--replacefiles` has just the same meaning as `--force`

Comment: What do you recommend instead, erasing the old package and installing the new like suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67324984/2147927)?

Answer (score 12):

This method worked for me, when I faced similar issue

Simply get the existing package with below command

```
rpm -qa | grep xenco
```

Remove those conflicting package with

```
yum remove packageNameFromTheList
```

Comment: yum remove compat-mysql51-5.1.73-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (this was an ancient unwanted leftover preventing yum update of mysql-community-server)

Answer (score 6):

what i always do is remove the package that is on the right hand side. In your case it would be -

```
yum remove xenco-server-1.9.6-104.x86_64
```

yum remove <> can work with any package error, i have encountered many such transactions errors when working on vm on cloud, i always remove the package that causes conflicts and always has worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

My two cents:

```
yum erase ${old_package}
yum install ${new_package_with_same_files}
```

The exclusion of `--replacefiles` is intentional. Yum is a package manager, let it manage the packages.

(This answer adds a `yum`-only solution to the accepted answer.)

Comment: You can also use `yum swap -- remove xenco-server -- install xenco-rr` if you have many dependencies and you don't want to uninstall everything.