# Installing php-pecl-memcache via yum tries to install php-cli, which conflicts with EasyApache's version

Tags: php, centos, memcached, easyapache-4

I'm running 64-bit CentOS 7 with cPanel/WHM/EasyApache 4, and am trying to get memcache and memcached (PHP) installed.

I installed memcache via yum without a hitch, but when trying to "yum install php-pecl-memcached", this is the error I get:

```
Transaction check error:

file /usr/bin/php from install of php-cli-5.4.16-42.el7.x86_64
 conflicts with file from package ea-php-cli-0.1.0-2.4.1.cpanel.x86_64
```

This is happening on a live site, so I want to confirm that I can uninstall php-cli via EasyApache without affecting my front end. (I also tried installing memcached via EasyApache, but it complains about not being able to find libmemcached, which is not available through that interface.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable yum transaction check for file conflict](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21246680/disable-yum-transaction-check-for-file-conflict)

Comment: @CPHPython My only concern with using the --replacefiles flag is that the version numbers are different. I understand that it's EA's versioning, but I want to confirm that it's safe to do so.